# How to initialize a structure within a structure in C?

Tags: c, struct, initialization, structure

I have these two structures :

```
struct member {
  char *nickname;
  char *group;
};

struct node {
   struct member mbr;
   struct node   *next;
};
```

Further in my code I do this :

```
struct node* n = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

And get a "Segmentation fault" error at this line when I run the program :

```
strcopy(n->mbr.nickname, temp->nickname);
```

I've been trying for a while to solve this problem and I've searched on the web, but I didn't find any solution yet. I'm guessing the structure inside 'n' isn't initialized. I did a few test that looked like :

```
n->mbr = (struct member*)malloc(sizeof(struct member));
```

But then I get another error : "incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct member' from type 'struct member *'"...

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Is `strcopy()` a typo or your own function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need to allocate `mbr`; you need to allocate `mbr.nickname`.

```
struct node* n = malloc(sizeof (struct node));
n->mbr.nickname = malloc(some number of characters);
```

Then use `strncpy`. Alternatively,

```
n->mbr.nickname = strdup(temp->nickname);
```

which is the same as doing that, but using `strlen(temp->nickname) + 1` as the size.

Comment: Hm, `strncpy` is not such a good idea when the length of the string is known, anyhow. Better use `memcpy`, then.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Is the length of the string known? If the idea is to find it using `temp->nickname`, I’ve added `strdup`.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that strdup is POSIX and not standard C.

Comment: OP tagged C, not posix - stick with `strlen(x)`  (no strndup or strdup)

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much, it's been a while since the last time I did some C programming and I think I'm not quite back into it ;)